# Why do we introduce artificial variable for equality constraints in two phase simplex method?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, constraints, simplex

Say we have a linear program where we wish to maximise some function Z, and we have the following equality constraints:

$3x_1 + 2x_2 + x_3 + 2x_4 = 225$

$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 117$

$4x_1 + 3x_2 + 3x_3 + 4x_4 = 420$

Why would we need to add artificial variables to each of the constraints in the first phase of the two phase simplex method?

Why is it not sufficient to set 4-3 = 1 (4 decision variables and 3 constraint equations) of the decision variables to 0 and solve to find an initial basic feasible solution?

E.g. if we chose $x_1 = 0$, we could find $x_2 =39, x_3 = 9, x_4 = 69$. This looks like a basic feasible solution to me, which surely means it could be used as an initial vertex for the simplex algorithm? Though I am unsure how this BFS might be represented/arranged in the initial tableau.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues with linear dependence that are not too troubling; e.g. in
\begin{align}
   2x_1 + x_2 - x_3 &= 5 \\
   3x_1 + x_2 - x_3 &= 6
\end{align}
you should not set $x_1$ to $0$ and try to solve for $x_2, x_3$ because you will fail. But that's not the real reason; Gaussian elimination exists to solve this kind of problem.

The problem is that picking some basic variables at random like you're suggesting will give you a *basic* solution, but that solution will only be *feasible* by chance. When you chose $x_1 = 0$ and got $x_2 =39$, $x_3 = 9$, and $x_4 = 69$, you won three coin flips in a row by getting $x_2 \ge 0$, $x_3 \ge 0$, and $x_4 \ge 0$. In a system with $50$ variables and $100$ equations, setting $50$ variables to $0$ arbitrarily has a $\frac1{2^{50}}$ chance of working, which is basically $0$.

(In my example above, which has easier numbers: if you set $x_1=0$, you don't get a basic solution. If you set $x_2=0$, you get $x_1=1$ and $x_3 = -3$, which is not feasible. Only if you set $x_3 = 0$ do you get a basic solution: $x_1 = 1$, $x_2 = 3$.)

Not only does *this* method not work, we know that in general, there's *no* method to find an initial basic solution which takes less effort than solving a linear program from a basic solution. Phase I is just as hard as Phase II. That's because it's possible (most easily using duality, which you probably have not learned yet) to turn an optimization problem (maximize this linear function subject to these equations and inequalities) into a feasibility problem (find a point that satisfies all these equations and inequalities). This tells us that there can't be an easy trick that does feasibility much faster than optimization.

Comment: Ah I see thank you, that makes a lot more sense. A side question, though I did get lucky in acquiring an initial BFS for the problem by arbitrarily picking a basic variable, how exactly could I represent this BFS in the initial tableau for the second phase? I'm struggling to see how it might look.

Comment: For the tableau, having just the values $(0, 39, 9, 69)$ is actually not enough. You want to move $x_1$ to the other side and treat it as a constant; then, when you solve for $x_2, x_3, x_4$, you will get $x_2 = 39 - x_1$, $x_3 = 9 + x_1$, and $x_4 = 69 - x_1$. (This is also the output of appropriately-done Gaussian elimination in which you make $x_2, x_3, x_4$ the pivots.) Now you can put it into a tableau, though the exact way your tableau will look depends on your notation a lot.

Comment: Ohh okay that's perfect thanks so much!